# CartoCSS: style a layer based on proximity to another layer

Tags: css, google-maps, mapbox, cartocss

I am trying to replicate a google maps style in CartoCSS with Map box studio classic. A default google map has a light brown shading for the industrial area surrounding an airport (as in the screenshot)

Google Maps San Francisco Airport - the target style

[image: Google maps - San Francisco airport]

Mapbox San Francisco Airport - the current style

[image: Mapbox San Francisco Airport]

The area "underneath" the airport is classed as #Landuse['industrial']. I'm looking for a method to give this area the light brown shading but leaving all other industrial areas unaffected.

I'm thinking down the lines of applying a style to any #Landuse['industrial'] which is in proximity to any #aeroway layer. So the question is: Is this possible and/or is there a better/easier way to achieve the desired style.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to style elements based on their proximity in CartoCSS - that kind of geometric filter wouldn't be performant. If the landuse has a unique ID, the best way to solve this problem would be filtering by ID and shading this specific instance.

Comment: I presume the ID's are unique to each airport so in order for the style sheet to work for any generic airport, I would need a lookup of "airport landuse industry" for every airport in the world?